# Address fields in FormBuilder

Tags: addresses, formbuilder

I have a FormBuilder form with an individual and an organization. I would like to add address fields for the organization. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

Address fields are added by the "Contact Address(es)" block, rather than as individual fields:

Blocks aren't heavily used yet in FormBuilder, but they allow you to save a set of fields together to be reused.

[image]